# What does ::1 stands for in Exim mainlog in rip and lip in log?

Tags: centos, exim

I have suspicious log line, where someone logged in client webmail, and there is no remote or local IP logged, there just stands `::1`. What does that mean?

Line is like here:

```
H=(webmail.domain.com) [::1]:33260
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::1` is just the IPv6 address for `localhost`.  Therefore, someone (probably you?) logged in to the webmail interface from the server itself.